# Can't upload images to a public directory in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, image-uploading

I'm trying to upload images into a Laravel app that will then need to be publicly displayed. However, I seem to only be able to upload to a folder within the application root. Any attempt to upload to the public directory throws the following error:

```
protected function getTargetFile($directory, $name = null)
{
    if (!is_dir($directory)) {
        if (false === @mkdir($directory, 0777, true)) {
            throw new FileException(sprintf('Unable to create the "%s" directory', $directory));
```

I'm assuming this means that Laravel is going to prevent me from uploading to any file that is publicly accessible. I actually rather like this, however, how can I link to images that are outside of the public directory I've tried to ../ my way out of the public folder, but appropriately, that didn't work.

Alternately, anything that will let me uploaded directly to the public folder would be great too.

If it helps, here is my controller method that puts the file in public folder:

```
$thumbnail_file = Input::file('thumbnail'); 
$destinationPath = '/uploads/'. str_random(8);
$thumbnail_filename = $thumbnail_file->getClientOriginalName();
$uploadSuccess = Input::file('thumbnail_url')->move($destinationPath, $thumbnail_filename);
```

Comment: Just to ring some bells. You can use 0755 as permission mode and if you want to create random file or folder names you can use time() function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your destination path should be:

```
 $destinationPath = public_path(sprintf("\\uploads\\%s\\", str_random(8)));
```

Comment: You need to escape all the backslashes --> $destinationPath = public_path().sprintf("\\uploads\\%s\\", str_random(8));

Comment: I get error: `Impossible to create the root directory `

Answer (score 8):

```
Route::post('upload', function(){
   $avarta = Input::file('avatar');
   if(strpos($avarta->getClientMimeType(),'image') !== FALSE){

      $upload_folder = '/assets/uploads/';

      $file_name = str_random(). '.' . $avarta->getClientOriginalExtension();

      $avarta->move(public_path() . $upload_folder, $file_name);

      echo URL::asset($upload_folder . $file_name);  // get upload file url

      return Response::make('Success', 200);
   }else{
     return Response::make('Avatar must be image', 400); // bad request
  }});
```

will upload to  `/public/assets/uploads` folder, maybe help you

Answer (score 1):

Try using this one in your controller after creating a folder called uploads in your public and another folder called photos in uploads.

```
 $data = Input::all();
    $rules = array(           
        'photo' => 'between:1,5000|upload:image/gif,image/jpg,image/png,image/jpeg',            
    );
    $messages = array(
        'upload' => 'The :attribute must be one of the following types .jpg .gif .png .jpeg',
        'between' => 'The :attribute file size must be 1kb - 5mb'
    );

    $validator = Validator::make($data, $rules, $messages);
    if($validator->passes())
    {
        $uploads = public_path() . '/uploads/photos';
        $photo = Input::file('photo');
        $photodestinationPath = $uploads;

        $photoname = null;

        if($photo != null)
        {
            $photoname = $photo->getClientOriginalName();
            Input::file('photo')->move($photodestinationPath, $photoname);
        }

        $thumbnail = new Model_name();          
        $thumbnail ->column_name_in_table = $photoname;
```

and then put this in your routes

```
 Validator::extend('upload', function($attribute,$value, $parameters){
$count = 0;
for($i = 0; $i < count($parameters); $i++)
{
    if($value->getMimeType() == $parameters[$i])
    {
        $count++;
    }
}

if($count !=0)
{
    return true;
}
return false;});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the ImageProductController.php (Controller) file insert the following code:

```
public function store(Request $request, $id)
{
if ($request->hasFile('image')){
  $rules = [
    'image'  => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg'
  ];

  $this->validate($request, $rules);

// Save file in directory
  $file = $request->file('image');
  $path = public_path() . '/images';
  $fileName = md5(rand(0,9999)).'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
  $file->move($path, $fileName);

  $imageProduct = new ImageProduct();
  $imageProduct->image = $fileName;
}
```

In the file create.blade.php (View) insert the following code:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action=" " >
 {{ csrf_field() }}

      <label for="image" class="btn btn-primary">Inserir Imagem</label> 

      <input type="file" name="image" id="image"  accept="image/*" 
        class="form-control" value="{{ old('image') }}>   
</form>
```

In the ImageProduct.php file (Model) insert the following code:

```
public function getUrlAttribute()
{
    if(substr($this->image, 0, 4) === "http"){
        return $this->image;
    }

    return '/images/'.$this->image;
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

You need to give permission the laravel folder where you want to store images.
The commend is:

`sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/www/html/project-name/path/to/folder`.